# How to get rid of the 'Killed' after longtime running in a fortran program?

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran

I met the 'killed' problem when I run my f90 function for calculating autocorrelation function, in which I need calculate average over a number (`np`) of time series when the parameter`np` is very large.

When `np` is small,my code can work very well. But when `np` is quite large (`10^6`), The function is killed after some time of running. Could someone give any suggestion on this problem? The code is as follows.

```
     program acf
     implicit none
    !========================
    !parameters and variables
    !========================
    character(LEN=20) :: filename
    integer,parameter :: rk=4
    real,parameter :: rooc=29.16, rohc=12.25, cosphic=0.866
    real(kind=rk),parameter :: delta_t=0.005
    real           :: ave_qj
    integer        :: i,j,k,nmo,nat,iat,&
                    imo,np,m1,m2,m3,mt
    real(kind=rk),allocatable,dimension (:,:) :: r12, r13, r23,h
    real(kind=rk),allocatable,dimension (:,:) :: cosphi, pm
    real,allocatable,dimension (:,:)         :: x,y,z
    character(LEN=3),allocatable,dimension (:) :: atom_type
    integer,allocatable,dimension (:)   :: ndx_1, ndx_2, ndx_3
    real,allocatable,dimension (:)      :: qj
    real(kind=rk),allocatable,dimension (:) :: corr_h
    real(kind=rk),allocatable,dimension (:) :: scalar_h
    !==================
    !read data in input
    !==================
    open(10,file='acqjond_k_pair_input')
    read(10,*)filename
    read(10,*)nmo     !number of movie steps
    read(10,*)nat     !number of atoms per mole.
    read(10,*)np      !number of pairs   
    allocate(ndx_1(np))
    allocate(ndx_2(np))
    allocate(ndx_3(np))
    do k=1,np
       read(10,*)ndx_1(k),ndx_2(k),ndx_3(k)
    enddo
    close(10)
    !         
    allocate(atom_type(nat))
    allocate(x(nat,nmo))
    allocate(y(nat,nmo))
    allocate(z(nat,nmo))
    allocate(cosphi(nmo,np))
    allocate(pm(nmo,np))
    allocate(r12(nmo,np))
    allocate(r13(nmo,np))
    allocate(r23(nmo,np))
    allocate(h(nmo,np))
    allocate(qj(np))
    !=======================
    !read in trajectory file 
    !=======================
    open(10,file='traj_pos.xyz')
    do imo=1,nmo
       read(10,*)                  !Neglect data of this line
       read(10,*)                  !Neglect data of this line
       do iat= 1,nat
           read (10,*)atom_type(iat),x(iat,imo),&
                   y(iat,imo),z(iat,imo)
       enddo
    enddo
    close(10)
    !

    do k=1,np
        qj(k)=0
        m1=ndx_1(k)
        m2=ndx_2(k)
        m3=ndx_3(k)
        do j =1, nmo
            h(j,k)=0
            r13(j,k)= (x(m1,j)-x(m3,j))**2+  &
                      (y(m1,j)-y(m3,j))**2+  &
                      (z(m1,j)-z(m3,j))**2      !r:squra of distances
            r12(j,k)= (x(m1,j)-x(m2,j))**2+  &
                      (y(m1,j)-y(m2,j))**2+  &
                      (z(m1,j)-z(m2,j))**2
            r23(j,k)= (x(m2,j)-x(m3,j))**2+  &
                      (y(m2,j)-y(m3,j))**2+  &
                      (z(m2,j)-z(m3,j))**2
            pm(j,k)= (x(m3,j)-x(m2,j))*   &
                     (x(m1,j)-x(m2,j))+   &
                     (y(m3,j)-y(m2,j))*   &
                     (y(m1,j)-y(m2,j))+   &
                     (z(m3,j)-z(m2,j))*   &
                     (z(m1,j)-z(m2,j))
            cosphi(j,k)= pm(j,k)/(sqrt(r23(j,k)*r12(j,k)))                 
            if (r13(j,k) .lt. rohc .and. r12(j,k).lt.rooc          &
              .and. cosphi(j,k).gt. cosphic) then
              h(j,k)=1.0
              qj(k)=qj(k)+h(j,k)
            endif
         enddo
         qj(k)=qj(k)/nmo
     enddo
     deallocate (x,y,z,atom_type) 
    !================
    !Write the result
    !================
    open(10,file=trim(filename)//'_nqj.dat')
    do k=1,np
         write(10,*) k, qj(k)
         do j =1,nmo
             write(10,*)j,j*delta_t,h(j,k)
         enddo
     enddo
     close(10)
     deallocate (cosphi,pm,                                          &
             r12,r13,r23,ndx_1,ndx_2,ndx_3)
    !==================================
    !Calculate autocorrelation function
    !==================================
  allocate(corr_h(nmo))
  allocate(scalar_h(np))
  do i=1, nmo
      corr_h(i)=0
  enddo
  ave_qj=0.d0
  ! calculate ave_qj
  do k=1, np
      ave_qj=ave_qj+qj(k)
  enddo
  ave_qj=ave_qj/np
  write(6,*) ave_qj
  ! calculate <f(0)f(t)>/<f> 
  do mt=0,nmo-1     ! time interval
      do k=1, np
          scalar_h(k)=0.d0
          do j=1, nmo-mt-1
              scalar_h(k)=scalar_h(k)+h(j,k)*h(j+mt,k)
          enddo
          scalar_h(k)=scalar_h(k)/(nmo-mt)
          corr_h(mt+1)=corr_h(mt+1)+scalar_h(k)
      enddo
      corr_h(mt+1)=corr_h(mt+1)/(np*ave_qj)
    enddo
    !=====================
    !Write the correlation
    !C(t)       
    !=====================
    open(10,file=trim(filename)//'_acf_h.dat')
        do i=1,int(nmo*rate)
            write(10,*)i-1,corr_h(i)
        enddo
        write(6,*)'written in '//trim(filename)//'_acf_h.dat'
    close(10)
    !==============================================================
    end
```

Comment: Are you running in a queue environment? Please provide more information in general. Ideally you'd post your input files that fail on eg Dropbox so that people can reproduce.

Comment: How big is nmo? How big is nat? My strong suspicion is you are running out of memory. Related is why are you storing r12, r13, r23, pm and cosphi in arrays? From what I can see they could all be scalars, so saving memory

Comment: `nmo` is 10 thousand, `nat` is about 700. Thanks @IanBush  also think that is out of memory. I can upload the input later.

Comment: @lan Bush Yes, you are right! I do not need to use array for `r12`,`r13`,etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running out of memory with the code as written.If np=10^6, nmo=10000 and nat=700 the nmo by np arrays take 4*10000*10^6=4*10^11 bytes=400 Giga Bytes.

As noted in the comments you don't need most of the very large nmo by np arrays, and r12, r23, r13, cosphi and pm can be got rid of trivially. However as currently structured with the two loops you need the h array. I strongly suggest you restructure the code to get rid of this as well as otherwise you will run into the same problem. It is fairly easy to calculate h for just one value of the outer k loop, and then use that to calculate the contribution to the autocorrelation function, and then move onto the next k. That way you only need h to be of size nmo.

That still leaves a number of nat by nmo arrays. These require 4*700*10000=28Mbytes, which is much more manageable.

Oh, and I would swap the way round that you store x, y and z. This will get you much better data locality in the first main loops, as then the inner loop will go down the first index of these arrays, which is much more efficient than you have currently.